# Declaring Int variables causes segmentation fault?

Tags: c

Hey guys I'm having a really peculiar segmentation fault coming up in my program.   This program is suppose to automate the card game "war"  and so far I've been able to build two randomized half decks for both players. Which would appear to show that enqueue is working correct.  I was also able to dequeue all the values and they appeared in the correct order.  However inside main if I uncomment the integer declarations in main the program segfaults every time.  I can not for the life of me figure out how simple declarations could cause faults. Please note this is my only second assignment for using queues.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int value;
    int suit;
    char*sname;
    char*txt;
    struct node *next;
} node;
int isempty(node *base){
    if (base==NULL)
        {return 1;}
    else
        return 0;
}
void printlist(node *base){
    node *current=base;                                 
    if(base==NULL)
        {
            printf("The List is empty!\n");
            return;
        }
    else
        {
            printf("Content: \n");
            int count=0;
            while(current!=NULL){
                count++;
                printf("%s \tof \t%s\n",current->txt,current->sname);
                current=current->next;
            }                                                    
            printf("\nCount:%d\n",count);
        }
    }       
char* valname(int n){                                    
    char *name;                                          
    switch(n)                                            
    {                                                    
        case 0:name="two";break;                         
        case 1:name="three";break;                      
        case 2:name="four";break;                       
        case 3:name="five";break;                        
        case 4:name="six";break;                         
        case 5:name="seven";break;                       
        case 6:name="eight";break;                       
        case 7:name="nine";break;                        
        case 8:name="ten";break;                         
        case 9:name="Jack";break;
        case 10:name="Queen";break;
        case 11:name="King";break;
        case 12:name="Ace";break;
        default:printf("Broken\n");exit(1);             
    }                                                   
    return(name);                                        
}
char* suitname(int n){
    char *name;
    switch(n){
        case 0:name="Hearts";break;
        case 1:name="Spades";break;
        case 2:name="Clubs";break;
        case 3:name="Diamonds";break;
        default:printf("Broken\n");exit(1);
    }
    return(name);
}
void enqueue(node **base,int item){
node *nn,*current=*base;
nn=malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(*base==NULL)
    {
        *base=nn;
    }
    else
    {
        while(current->next!=NULL){
            current=current->next;
        }
        current->next=nn;
    }
    nn->value=item;
    nn->txt=valname(item%13);
    nn->sname=suitname(item/13);
    nn->next=NULL;
}
int dequeue(node **base){
node *current=*base,*temp;
    if (isempty(*base)==0){
        int giveback=current->value;
        if(current->next==NULL)
        {
            free(*base);
            *base=NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            temp=current->next;
            free(current);
            *base=temp;
        }
        return giveback;
    }else{return -1;}
}
void createdecks(node **deck1,node **deck2){
int i=0;
int thenumber=0;
int deck[52]={0};
for(i=0;i<26;i++){
        thenumber=rand()%52;
        if(deck[thenumber]==0){
            //add to list
            enqueue(deck1,thenumber);
            deck[thenumber]=1;
        }
        else
        {
            i--;
        }
    }
for(i=0;i<26;i++){
        thenumber=rand()%52;
        if(deck[thenumber]==0){
            //add to list
            enqueue(deck2,thenumber);
            deck[thenumber]=1;
        }
        else
        {
            i--;
        }
    }
}
int main(void){
    node *d1,*d2,*warholder;
    //int c1=0,c2=0;                    //THIS LINE!!!!!!!!!!!
    srand(time(NULL));
    createdecks(&d1,&d2);
    //printlist(d1);
    //printlist(d2);
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<26;i++)
        printf("%d ",dequeue(&d1)); //return testing
    printf("\n");
    printlist(d1);
}
```

Professor's example function

```
char * namenum( int num)
{
    char * name;
    switch(num)
    {
        case 0:
            name = "zero";  break;
        case 1:
            name = "one";   break;
        case 2:
            name = "two";   break;
        case 3:
            name = "three"; break;
        case 4:
            name = "four";  break;
        case 5:
            name = "five";  break;
        case 6:
            name = "six";   break;
        case 7:
            name = "seven"; break;
        case 8:
            name = "eight"; break;
        case 9:
            name = "nine"; break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid Number generated\n");
            exit(1);
    }
    return name;
}
```

Comment: Initialize your pointers in main, see if it goes away. I'd guess there's garbage on your stack that leads to the pointers being nonnull for the first insertion, though they're not pointing to any allocated memory. *edit* and having the zeroed ints declared affects the initial state of the pointers, and which is why your program runs with them set.

Comment: If you have Valgrind, try running it under this - it would detect the problem here instantly.

Comment: @Tyler please do not edit the question to say things like "answered" or "redacted" etc.  It makes it confusing for people seeing this question for the first time. Instead, accept a posted answer and that's all you need to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I briefly looked at the code, and it looks to me like you have an uninitialized-variable problem. You declare this in `main()`:

```
node *d1,*d2,*warholder;
```

And then you pass it to `createdecks()`, which in turn calls `enqueue()`. `enqueue()` assumes that the pointers are initialized.

Try to initialize `d1` and `d2` in `main()`:

```
node *d1,*d2,*warholder;
d1 = d2 = warholder = NULL;
```

Comment: I thought I took care of this in the enqueue function.

Comment: No @Tyler, variables declared in a function are *not* guaranteed to be initialized with a value unless you specify a value. You check if the base is null, which is good, but you're *relying* on base having been initialized to Null where it's originally declared (in main). If something happens to be on the stack, base may have a non null value,  even though you didn't assign anything to it.

Comment: Awesome dude thank you! That fixed everything right up!

Answer (score -2):

Its not due to declaring int. You have not allocated memory to char *name on several times before using it. for example

```
char* valname(int n){                                    
    char *name;
```

allocate memory using malloc() before using name after above code

```
char* suitname(int n){
    char *name;
```

same mistake again

If you want to avoid such situation use array instead of pointer

Comment: That is absolutely not the reason, because if `name` stays local to each of the functions, nothing bad will happen. When it's returned there it is where the problem happens.

Comment: Oh realy man???? And how would a value is assigned to char * when there is no memory for it??? I m gonna be mad

Comment: It's because you are assigning the pointer, not it's value. It's compilcated right! but once you get it, you will be a programming god. I think that you might be muslim so I hope it's not offensive to say programming god, my father is muslim too, I just can't understand the god theory so I am not.  Inside the function `name` points to the location where the string literal is stored, and it's valid. The location is the stack frame of the function, so when the function returns it's deallocated with the function.

Comment: Dude you said "so when the function returns it's deallocated with the function". How does it gets deallocated when its not allocated yet????

Comment: not in this situation it turns out I was wrong, when you use a `char` array this is true, but string literals have static storage.